# Função de pesquisar em agenda em C

Tags: c#, c, lógica

Olá, estou fazendo uma agenda em C e já fiz as partes de cadastrar contato, listar todos os contatos e deletar um contato, porém preciso elaborar a parte de pesquisar o contato, e também pesquisar contatos que iniciam com uma dada letra, mas não estou conseguindo... Vou deixar meu código abaixo para ver se alguém consegue me ajudar a identificar onde estou errando.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct
{
    char nome[50];
    char telefone[16];
    int bd;
    char bdm[10];
} Agenda;

int adicionarContato(Agenda **c, int quant, int tam)
{
    if (quant < tam)
    {
        Agenda *novo = malloc(sizeof(Agenda));
        printf("\nDigite o nome do contato a ser salvo: ");
        scanf("%s", &novo->nome);
        printf("\ndigite o seu telefone: ");
        scanf("%s", &novo->telefone);
        printf("\nDigite o dia do seu aniversário ");
        scanf("%d", &novo->bd);
        printf("\n digite o mês do seu nascimento: ");
        scanf("%s", &novo->bdm);
        c[quant] = novo;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Lista cheia.\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int deleteContact(Agenda **c, int quant)
{
    int id;

    QntContatos(c, quant);

    printf("\n\t Digite o número do usuário que você quer deletar: \n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    getchar();
    id--;
    if (id >= 0 && id < quant)
    {
        free(c[id]); //evitar vazamento de memória
        if (id < quant - 1)
        {
            c[id] = c[quant - 1];
        }
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\t código errado;\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void QntContatos(Agenda **c, int quant)
{
    int i;

    printf("\n Lista de contatos: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d = aniversário: %2d de %s\t nome do contato: %s \t telefone: %s\n", i + 1, c[i]->bd, c[i]->bdm, c[i]->nome, c[i]->telefone);
    }
}

void Pesquisar(int quant, Agenda **c)
{
    int i;
    char nomeBuscado[30];

    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        printf("\n digite o nome a ser pesquisado: \n");
        scanf("%s", &nomeBuscado);
        getchar();

        if (strcmp(nomeBuscado, c[i]->nome) == 0)
        {
            printf("o nome: %s foi encontrado com sucesso", c[i]->nome);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("o nome não foi encontrado");
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    Agenda *contatos[50];
    char arquivo[] = ("agenda.txt");
    int opcao, tam = 50, quant = 0;

    do
    {
        printf(" \n\t0 - exit\n\t1 - Cadastrar contato na agenda\n\t2 - Remover contato\n\t3- Imprimir contatos\n\t4- Pesquisar contato\n\t");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        getchar();

        switch (opcao)
        {
        case 1:
            quant += adicionarContato(contatos, quant, tam);
            break;
        case 2:
            quant += deleteContact(contatos, quant);
            break;
        case 3:
            QntContatos(contatos, quant);
            break;
        case 4:
            Pesquisar(contatos, quant);
            break;
        }
    } while (opcao != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está pedindo o nome a ser pesquisado a cada loop, deveria ser:

```
void Pesquisar(int quant, Agenda **c)
{
    int i;
    char nomeBuscado[30];

    printf("\n digite o nome a ser pesquisado: \n");
    scanf("%s", &nomeBuscado);
    getchar();

    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(nomeBuscado, c[i]->nome) == 0)
        {
            printf("o nome: %s foi encontrado com sucesso", c[i]->nome);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("o nome não foi encontrado");
        }
    }
}
```